# LibGDX, отрисовать часть Sprite

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отрисовать часть спрайта, при этом он должен сохранить свои пропорции. Сейчас отрисовывается спрайт полностью и при установки требуемой высоты он как бы "сжимается" (метеориты).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код которым я отрисовываю

```
batch.draw(meteorUp, web1.getX(), web1.getY(), web1.getWidth(), web1.getHeight());
```

где meteorUp спрайт, web1.getX(), web1.getY() - координаты,  web1.getWidth(), web1.getHeight() размер.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Нужна анимация спрайта?

Comment: да, нужна, они двигаются все разом (все метеориты)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.libgdx.ru/2013/11/spritebatch-textureregions-and-sprite.html

```
private  final int FRAME_COLS = 1; // кол-во изобр. в спрайте в ширину
private  final int FRAME_ROWS = 6; // кол-во изобр. в спрайте высоту
private TextureRegion region;
private Animation walkAnimation;
private Texture walkSheet;
private TextureRegion[] walkFrames;
private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
private TextureRegion currentFrame;

private float stateTime; // 


@Override
public void create() {

    walkSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("meteors.png")); // 
    region = new TextureRegion(walkSheet, 162, 184); // размер текстуры для вывода статического изобр.
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet, walkSheet.getWidth()/FRAME_COLS, walkSheet.getHeight()/FRAME_ROWS);

    walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }

    walkAnimation = new Animation(0.055f, walkFrames); //частота кадров в сек
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stateTime = 0f;
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}


@Override
public void render() {
    //Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);

    // Рисуем анимацию
    spriteBatch.begin();

        spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, 900, 500);

    //spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, 900, 500, 162*2, 184*2 );  // рисует анимацию (позиция по гориз., поз. по верт., ширина(изменить можно), высота)
    spriteBatch.end();
}



public void stopanim(){
    spriteBatch.begin();

        spriteBatch.draw(region, 900, 500);  // рисует отдельную текстуру

    spriteBatch.end();
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

    walkSheet.dispose();
    spriteBatch.dispose();
}

}
```

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Часть спрайта? Используй texture region.
Если хочешь чтоб он отрисовывался в полную свою величину, можешь getWidth и getHeight не писать